# Windows-equivalent of this linux command

Tags: windows, networking

How one could achieve something like this in Windows?

```
ifconfig eth0:10 192.168.121.1
ifconfig eth0:11 192.168.122.1
```

or a more-suggested way:

```
ip addr add 192.168.121.1/24 dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.122.1/24 dev eth0
```

I mean, multiple IP addresses on one interface. Basically I connect to the machines, where they can't see each other I see both.

Comment: Dear thelastblack, I hope this could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944860/how-to-create-an-ip-alias-on-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest `netsh` :

```
netsh interface ipv4 add address "Local Area Connection" 192.168.121.1 255.255.255.0
netsh interface ipv4 add address "Local Area Connection" 192.168.122.1 255.255.255.0
```

[Further reference can be found on Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc770948(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to switch between static and DHCP-assigned addresses:

For static:

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.3 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.3 1
```

For DHCP:

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

Comment: This sets an address, does not alias another one on interface :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest Powershell, since netsh is set to be deprecated (you don't specify the Windows version).

In Powershell:

```
Get-NetAdapter
```

to identify your network adapter. Then,

```
New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" –IPv4Address "192.168.1.1" –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.1.254
New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" –IPv4Address "192.168.2.1" –PrefixLength 24
```